# How to calculate checksum for stored procedure result row sets?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures

I am using `Visual Studio 2012 with Update 4` and `SQL Server Database Project` to create unit tests. The [unit test conditions namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.tools.schema.sql.unittesting.conditions(v=vs.103).aspx) includes `ChecksumCondition Class` which introduces the ability to compare one or more `SELECT` statements with others.

In order to use a `ChecksumCondition Class`, in the `Visual Studio` I need to define a `checksum` for comparison using the following interface:

[image]

and the `Visual Studio` is calculating the `checksum` for the given query/stored procedure/function behind the scene and returns it.

Could anyone say how to calculate this checksum for given query alone, using the `.net` code behind the interface above?

I need to do this, because I want to test the outputs of different versions of the same stored procedure. So, I need to calculate the checksums twice (executing each stored procedure version) and then compare them? Also, I want to be able to calculate this checksum in `.net` as I am going to calculate and compare many `checksums` executing the stored procedure with different parameters.